# How check variable for empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsrender

I have template this a part:

```
<td>{{=name}}</td>]
```

I need check name of null/empty and not display it.

How do this?

example:

```
{{#if ($name!= "" && $secondName!= "") }}
```

I get error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &&`

Comment: check here http://api.jquery.com/empty/

Comment: get error @Uncaught Expected block tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [jsrender](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender) then

```
{{if name}}
```

should do the trick

You can find a lot of scenarios solved in the [jsrender demo section](http://borismoore.github.com/jsrender/demos/demos.html).

Answer (score 1):

you can use `if(name && name !='' )` for more Security !!

Comment: Before anyone chooses to [recommend deletion](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11114709) of this post, this is a valid attempted answer. This post should not have been flagged and should not be recommended for deletion in the LQPRQ. See: [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563) and [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an out-of-date version of JsRender? The syntax is `{{:name}}`, and it automatically renders an empty string is name is undefined or null. Unit test here: https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender/blob/master/test/unit-tests/tests-jsrender-no-jquery.js#L108

With the latest version you can even write `{{:a.b.c.name noerror=true}}` and it will render the empty string even if any of `name`, or `a.b.c` or `a.b` or `a` are undefined or null.

You don't need to wrap in an `{{if ...}}...{{/if}}`